# How can you remove an iframe with no ID / Class , but based on its scr

Tags: jquery, iframe

How can i use jQuery to remove an iframe by targeting the scr.

I have the following iframe , that i want to remove on page load

```
<iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="/ads/remove_this_js.html"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selector string `[src="/ads/remove_this_js.html"]`:

```
document.querySelector('[src="/ads/remove_this_js.html"]').remove();
```

Comment: what is difference  $("[src=/ads/remove_this_js.html]").remove();  and $('[src="/ads/remove_this_js.html"]').remove();   , are either ok ?

Comment: They're the same, just like `<div class="foo">` and `<div class='foo'>` are both OK

Comment: i understand foo , but one has 2 quotes inside and the other 1 set of quotes " and '  , while the other only has "

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Some characters have a special meaning in a selector string, or can't be properly parsed as a selector without wrapping them in quotes. Just to be safe, I always wrap the attribute values in quotes. It's *usually* not an issue

Answer (score 1):

Use ***`[attribute=value]`*** selector is
**`[src=/ads/remove_this_js..html]`**

Example :
Using ***`.remove()`***

**`$("[src=/ads/remove_this_js.html]").remove();`**

---

Or also you can use ***`.hide()`***

**`$("[src=/ads/remove_this_js.html]").hide();`**

Comment: what is difference $("[src=/ads/remove_this_js.html]").remove(); and $('[src="/ads/remove_this_js.html"]').remove(); , are either ok ?

Comment: You can not use double quotes("") after 'src=', because it consider string by default like "ads/remove_this_js.html". if you are adding double quotes("") after 'src=' then it is consider value like json. For example it consider your src value like "\"/ads/remove_this_js.html\"" than that value is not matching with your ifram's src atribute.